# Merge two iter efficiently

Tags: python, python-3.x, merge, iterator

Need to design a method that takes an huge iter lets assume of size n, an operation min/max/etc is performed on it only for m iterations, finally method has to return output of operation and an copy of the input iter.

n tends to infinite, m tends to postive number less than n.

```
copy_it =  merge(poped_iter, it)
```

Using itertools.tee an iter could be cloned however internally it will iterate ove the iter, and if iter is huge it will take some n amount of time. I am looking a way to merge two iter without iterating on them.

```
def some_operation_and_copy_iter(it: iter, m: int) -> (int, iter):
    import itertools
    it, copy_it = itertools.tee(it)

    poped_data = []
    # Some operation on it
    max = -1
    i = 0
    while i < m:
        data = next(it)
        poped_data.append(data)
        if data >= max:
            max = data
        i += 1

    poped_iter = iter(poped_data)
    # copy_it =  merge(poped_iter, it)
    return max, copy_it


max, it = some_operation_and_copy_iter(iter(range(0, 1000000)), 100)
assert max == 99
assert list(it) == list(iter(range(0, 1000000)))
```

Comment: I guess you are looking for itertools.chain

Comment: Tip: if your arguments are `(iter, int)` it is better to return values in the same order `(iter, int)` not `(int, iter)`

Comment: Just do `copy_it = itertools.chain(poped_iter, it)`.

Comment: @DanielMesejo yes I am looking for something like itertools.chain, it works as expected. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

use [peekable](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.peekable) in [more_itertools](https://pypi.org/project/more-itertools/) when the operation needs on the subset of the iterator.
The peek operation runs on the subset of the iterator and the size is relatively small.

```py
from more_itertools import peekable
peekable_iter = peekable(iter(range(0, 1000000)))
m = 100
max_value = max(peekable_iter[0:m])

# do some operation on peekable_iter
```